# Deis.io - How to debug apps which aren't running?

Tags: docker, coreos, deis

apps suddenly decide not to work any more, and can't figure out how to debug the apps.

I get the following:

```
deis logs

404 NOT FOUND
No logs for karmic-anaconda

deis apps:info

--- admin:
admin.1 down (v6)

--- web:
web.1 down (v6)
```

Also I'm getting the default nginx page.

The Proc files have not changed.

---

I'm using:

Deis.io 0.8 with 3 CoreOS nodes

---

**Any idea how I would go on about debugging these apps, if no logs are available?**

Hopefully this will be useful to someone else as well in the same situation. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can debug the application by SSH'ing into your cluster and by checking the controller's logs. To do that, run the following:

```
$ fleetctl ssh deis-controller.service
$ docker logs deis-controller
```